# Executing a JavaScript in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to execute a Java script file in MongoDB at port 5930. Mongo can listen to the Database on that port:

```
./mongo localhost:5930
connecting to: localhost:5930/test
Server has startup warnings: 
Wed Dec 18 13:15:58.906 [initandlisten] 
Wed Dec 18 13:15:58.906 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory is 2
Wed Dec 18 13:15:58.906 [initandlisten] **          Journaling works best with it set to 0 or 1
```

Now when I execute test.js at port 5930 but I get the following error:

```
./mongo test.js
connecting to: test
Wed Dec 18 13:22:56.011 JavaScript execution failed: Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112
exception: connect failed
```

The test.js has the following line:

```
conn = new Mongo("localhost:5930);
```

How can I run the script at port 5930? and Why did the script always try to execute from the default port (27017)?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "Executing in MongoDB"? Are you executing a script in the Mongo shell? What is running on port 5930, node.js? Please post a few lines of your script that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Mongo is running at port 5930. Right now the script has only one line--> conn = new Mongo("localhost:5930); I am not running the script in the Mongo Shell rather using the ./mongo test.js command to execute the script.

Comment: `mongo localhost:5930 test.js`? You always need someplace to connect to in order to run script, regardless of the fact that the script creates a connection.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo tries to connect itself to the local database automatically, before it looks at your script.

Connect to a local Mongo database running on an alternate port with this [mongo command line](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongo-shell/):

```
mongo --nodb test.js
```

And have your code open the connection (which you already do).